# Search an two dimensional array by another array

Tags: ruby

I have two arrays. One Mapper and one with my ID's.

My Array with the external ID's:

`genres_array = [12,28,16]`

The Mapper Array (Internal-ID, External-ID)

```
mapper = [
   [1,12],
   [2,18],
   [3,19],
   [4,28],
   [5,16],
   [6,90],
]
```

As Result i would like to have now a new array, with only the internal values of the genres_array (the genres_array had the external values first). In this case the result would be `[1,4,5]`

I tried a lot of ways but i really have no idea how to solve this simple problem in a clean way. Im pretty sure it will be something like

`genres_array.map { |genre_id| get_internal_id_from_mapper }`

PS: It could also happen that a ID won't be found in the mapper. In that i case i just want to remove it from the array. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for `rassoc`:

```
genres_array.map { |genre_id| mapper.rassoc(genre_id)[0] }
```

Which results in

```
[1, 4, 5]
```

---

EDIT: Just read the PS - try something like this:

```
genres_array.map { |genre_id|
    subarr = mapper.rassoc genre_id
    subarr[0] if subarr
}.compact
```

Then for an input of

```
genres_array = [12,28,100,16]
```

You would still get the output

```
[1, 4, 5]
```

Comment: Thank you thats a very clean solution! Only one problem: If i have an id in my genres_array, that doesn't exists in the mapper array, i'm getting this exception: `NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass`

Answer (score 1):

Another way that won't throw an exception if the external id is not found:

```
genres_array = [12,28,16]

mapper = [
   [1,12],
   [2,18],
   [3,19],
   [4,28],
   [5,16],
   [6,90],
]

internal_ids = genres_array.map do |genre_id|
  element = mapper.detect { |m| m[1] == genre_id }
  element ? element[0] : nil
end.compact
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution involving a hash:

```
Hash[mapper].invert.values_at(*genres_array)
```

Asking for values that does not exist will return nil, if you do not want the nil just add `.compact` at the end.